# Disable vibration on flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, notifications

I'm using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to provide notifications for my application and I want to show them without any sound or vibration.
When I'm configuring the ChannelSpecifics for Android I specifically set to false `enableVibration`

```dart
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'id', 'name', 'description',
        importance: Importance.Max,
        priority: Priority.High,
        ongoing: true,
        enableVibration: false);
```

But anyway I'm still getting the vibration. Is there any other way to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

Once the settings for a notification channel has been specified, it remains the same for the entire lifetime of that channel. I suspect you've reused the same channel id back when *enableVibration* was set to true

Comment: On the configuration I'm doing I'm not specifying this in any other way but the one I show in the question.